# Strikethrough thickness for NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

I am annotating a mutable attributed string with a strikethrough in objective-c. Using the following code.

```
[MAString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                     value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])]
```

I am not clear what the value parameter controls and what its possible values are. Does it control thickness? If so, what are the possible values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about having a look to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nsstrikethroughstyleattributename)?

> This value indicates whether the text has a line through it and corresponds to one of the constants described in NSUnderlineStyle. The default value for this attribute is styleNone.

And then:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nsunderlinestyle

Comment: I can use the answer without the snarky putdown.

Comment: "Snarky put down" for the hint, that the answer is given in the docs? In the docs of the identifier itself, not hidden in multipage conceptual articles. Reading the docs before asking a Q on SO is what everyone can expect. If you do not do that, you should ask yourself, why.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is for lazy programmers**

```
extension String {

/// Apply strike font on text
    func strikeThrough(lineThickness:Int,lineColor:UIColor) -> NSAttributedString {
  let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
    attributeString.addAttribute(
    NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle,
    value: lineThickness,
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributeString.length))
    attributeString.addAttribute(
    NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor,
    value: lineColor,
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributeString.length))
    return attributeString
   }
 }
```

**Usage**

```
yourlabel.attributedText = "your text".strikeThrough(lineThickness: 3, lineColor: .red)
```